# ASP.Net routing problem

Tags: .net, asp.net

I defined my routed page as following:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
        "gans",
        "MyRoutedPage",
        "~/GardenTemplates/template4.aspx");
```

The web form template4.aspx has an image gallery: when user presses a small image,
it is displayed in big image:

```
//template4.aspx.cs

string imageName = "../Images2/garden/2206/SomePhoto.jpg";
img.Attributes["onclick"] = "LoadGallery('" + imageName + "');                

//template4.aspx

<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadGallery(imageName) {
    var picture = document.getElementById('Gallery');
    if (picture != null) {
        picture.src = imageFile;
    }
}
</script>
```

This code works fine if I browse to /GardenTemplates/template4.aspx
but it showse a directory list of GardenTemplates/ when I press the small image from
MyRouted page.
My guess is that Routing can not display files in upper directory (as Images2 is located in parent directory regarding the template4.aspx page).
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately ResolveClientUrl didn't help. 
I still go to file listing of directory GardenTempates/#

I do not understand why this happens only when offering to javascript

Comment: I've merged your accounts, you can now leave comments and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

ResolveClientUrl should help.  This looks like a client side issue.  Try something like -

```
img.Attributes["onclick"] = "LoadGallery('" + ResolveClientUrl(imageName) + "');
```

or...

```
img.Attributes["onclick"] = "LoadGallery('" + ResolveClientUrl("~/Images2/garden/2206/SomePhoto.jpg") + "');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately ResolveClientUrl didn't help. I still go to file listing of directory GardenTempates/# I do not understand why this happens only when offering to javascript